# nosuid doesn't prevent chmod u+s

Tags: partition, fstab, chmod, automounting

I follow a tutorial to secure my */etc/fstab* file. This is a certain part about */var* and */tmp*

```
UUID=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX /var ext4 defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 1 2
UUID=ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ /tmp ext4 defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 1 2
```

I executed the following commands to test the configuration :

```
touch /tmp/testFile
chmod u+s /tmp/testFile
```

I was expecting an error message but nothing... Is it normal ? Is it dangerous ?

Comment: Did you check with `ls /tmp/testFile` if you have SUID on file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nosuid` doesn’t prevent setting the bits; it means that they don’t have any effect. (That way, previously-set bits are also rendered ineffective.)

Setting the bits is only dangerous if the file system is later mounted without `nosuid`; but if anyone has sufficient access to set those bits on your file system, you’ve lost anyway.